# Change label text of react chartjs into image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a graph which made up of `react-chartjs`. Right now it has a text label. What I want is to put an image in the place of label text. I tried to add an image in the label but instead of showing an image, it is showing the path of that image.

Graph Data State variable

```
graphData: {
  labels: ['4 A.M', '5 A.M', '6 A.M', '7 A.M', '8 A.M', '9 A.M', '10 A.M', '11 A.M', '12 P.M', '1 P.M', '2 P.M', '3 P.M', '4 P.M', '5 P.M', '6 P.M', '7 P.M', '8 P.M', '9 P.M', '10 P.M', '11 P.M', '12 A.M', '1 A.M', '2 A.M', '3 A.M'],
  datasets: [{
      label: User, //User image is imported in this component
      backgroundColor: "#69c9e0",
      borderColor: '#69c9e0',
      borderWidth: 2,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      fill: true,
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
    },
    {
      label: User, //User image is imported in the label
      backgroundColor: "#f8a046",
      borderColor: '#f8a046',
      borderWidth: 2,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      fill: true,
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Title return text. For images you should use/read about this technique (Custom HTML tooltips): https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In your case, you can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw images (icons) instead of tick labels directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

The plugin would be defined as follows:

```
const plugins = [{
  afterDraw: chart => {
    let ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
    ctx.save();
    let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
    let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
    xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {  
      let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);      
      let image = new Image();
      image.src = ..., // provide the image URL
      ctx.drawImage(image, x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10);
    });  
    ctx.restore();    
}];
```

Then tell the `Bar` element about the `plugin` to be used.

```
<Bar
  ... 
  plugins={plugins}
/>
```

Also add some extra space at the bottom of the chart by defining `layout.padding.bottom` inside the chart `options`, otherwise the text won't be visible.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 60
  }
},
```